# How to manually destroy or recreate a ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-viewmodel

Working on an Android app where each user can have multiple accounts under the same login. There is a single activity with a fragment per tab - based on the Android sample Bottom Navigation.

On one of the tabs is a calendar, which is hooked up to a ViewModel like so:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        val calendarViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CalendarViewModel::class.java)

        calendarViewModel.calendarEvents.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            // Code that modifies the UI to show the events on a given day
        }

        val progressBar: ProgressBar = binding.progressBar
        calendarViewModel.calendarState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
           // Progress bar / error state handling code
        }
    }
```

On one of the other fragments (different tab in the bottom tab bar), I allow the user to switch accounts. When I come back to the calendar fragment/tab, the viewModel is still in scope so I have incorrect data for this user.

How can I manually force the ViewModelProvider to recreate the viewModel in onCreateView? Is there some way I can invalidate the ViewModel scope and force a re-pull of the data?

Comment: Where is the data for calendar events coming from? A good way to approach this task is to have `calendarEvents` re-emit the data for the newly-selected user, that way you won't need to destroy the ViewModel.

Comment: It's LiveData, which itself is driven through a repository/network call. What you are saying makes sense... are there suggested patterns for 'cross fragment' communication so I know when to trigger that re-emission? My 'active account' is stored in userPrefs, but since onCreateView is called when I navigate back I've been struggling to understand where to put the 'this is a different account so please re-emit data' flag.

Comment: Your ViewModel should subscribe to userPrefs changes and re-emit data whenever userPrefs change.

Comment: Thanks Egor, the sharedPreferences on change listener was exactly what I was looking for! Working well now.